# How to create a temporary table in snowflake based on pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can read the snowflake table in pyspark dataframe using sqlContext

```
sql = f"""select * from table1""";


 df = sqlContext.read
            .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
            .options(**snowflake_options)
            .option("query", sql)
            .load()
```

How do I create a temporary table in snowflake (using pyspark code) and insert values from this pyspark dataframe (df)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done. At least not the way you want.

You can, technically, create a temporary table; but persisting it is something that I have had a great deal of difficulty finding how to do (i.e. I haven't). If you run the following:

```
spark.sparkContext._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery(snowflake_options, 'create temporary table tmp_table (id int, value text)')
```

you'll notice that it successfully returns a java object indicating the temp table was created successfully; but once you try and run any further statements on it, you'll get nasty errors that mean it no longer exists. Somehow we mere mortals would need to find a way to access and persist the Snowflake session through the jvm api. That being said, I also think that would run contrary to the Spark paradigm.

If you really need the special-case performance boost of running transformations on Snowflake instead of bringing it all into Spark, just keep everything in Snowflake to begin with by either

1. Using CTEs in the query, or
2. Using the `runQuery` api described above to create "temporary" permanent/transient tables and designing Snowflake queries that insert directly to those and then clean them up (DROP them) when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

just save as usual, with snowflake format

```py
snowflake_options = {
    ...
    'sfDatabase': 'dbabc',
    'dbtable': 'tablexyz',
    ...
}
        
(df
    .write
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(**snowflake_options)
    .save()
)
```